# How to Compress uuid to a 62 binary by php

Tags: php, algorithm

How to Compress uuid to a 62 binary by php?

I want to generated a shorted url and the url param is a key compress the uuid

```
select replace(uuid(), '-', '')
```

The uuid is a 16 binary string and the uuid's length is 32 (varchar(32))
So the uuid is longer than max int.

How to Compress it to a 62 binary string (PHP)?

Comment: UUID's are 128bit. So the size of the string you'll get is (128/8 = 16bytes).

Comment: 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: A Google search for "PHP base 62" found this: http://www.lalit.org/lab/base62-php-convert-number-to-base-62-for-short-urls/. I can't make any guarantees about quality.

Comment: The Base62 used intval(), but the uuid (ps:d4e7df90bd6811e2991e00163ede213d) is longer than integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you convert a hex-encoded string to binary (in this case just the letters `hello`):

```
$str = hex2bin('68656c6c6f');
echo $str;
// output: hello
```

If you have an older version of PHP (5.3 and below), you can use the `pack` function:

```
$str = pack('H*', '68656c6c6f');
echo $str;
// output: hello
```

Comment: $str = hex2bin('d4e7df90bd6811e2991e00163ede213d'); Can it work?

Comment: hex2bin (PHP >= 5.4.0) Sorry I'am using php 5.3

Comment: @nomaka I updated my answer with a way of doing it in older PHP versions.

Comment: DO NOT use `hex2bin`, because it will get wrong results if the binary has to be longer than 32b. So it will fail if you try to encode any UUID! Always use `pack`!